# System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#

What is the error in c#?

[image: Error]

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'PopupControl, Version=1.4.0.968, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=04c10344d6495b18' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](//stackoverflow.com/q/4469929)

Comment: I found the solution here, It's a dll reference issue. When I deploy the .exe file I got an issue. But now .exe and along with the supporting dll and reference files are compressed as a .zip format. Finally I deploy the .zip file as a web job. It's working fine now as I expected.
did you already look at this? https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31